# Must goods be unused to get Spanish VAT refunded?

Tags: spain, tax-refunds, vat

Suppose I visit Spain, buy an expensive item, get the seller to provide a DIVA form, intending to get a VAT refund upon returning to my non-EU country of residence. It’s the kind of item that can be put to use during my stay in Spain. Can I start using it without endangering the refund?

- GlobalBlue, one of the largest tax refund companies, [requires](https://cs.globalblue.com/s/article/Getting-Your-Tax-Free-Form-Stamped) “unused goods (should be sealed in the original package)”.
- [The VAT law](https://www.boe.es/buscar/act.php?id=BOE-A-1992-28740) and [the VAT regulations](https://www.boe.es/buscar/act.php?id=BOE-A-1992-28925) do not seem to contain such a requirement. Not only that, the latter explicitly exempts (9.1.3.º) from VAT works performed on goods to be exported, which certainly don’t leave the goods in the unused and sealed state.

So which one is it?

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/124600/what-are-unused-goods-for-the-purpose-of-tax-free-shopping asks what the term _unused_ stands for, while I’d like to figure out whether it’s applicable at all.

Comment: VAT is a **consumer** tax. If you **using** it while in Spain, then it is no longer "unused" (being "consumed").

Comment: @MarkJohnson That might be the spirit of the law, or maybe that isn’t even the case and the idea of the tax is to tax _Spanish consumers,_ not to mention that the spirit of the exemption is to make the country more competitive lest the likes of me go elsewhere to buy expensive things, but anyway, the question is—what’s the letter of the law?

Comment: The [EU guide on VAT refunds for non-EU tourists](https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/guide-vat-refund-visitors-eu_en) do not mention any requirement for the goods to be unused. Neither does the equivalent for France. Too lazy to read Spanish legalese at this time, though.

Comment: That is wishfull thinking on your part. Anyone who **consumes/uses** it within the European Union must pay the tax. You have quoted a Spanish source, here's another that is more specific: [German VAT Refund - Federal Foreign Office](https://www.germany.info/us-en/service/09-Taxes/vat-refund/906296): **the purchased goods (unused/unworn in its original packaging and with price tag)**